# NextJs Image Optimisation Error ERROR:INVALID_IMAGE_OPTIMIZE_REQUEST

Tags: next.js, vercel, nextjs-image

Next Js image is working properly in the local environment but in production, the images are showing for some domains and not showing for some domains for example image is working fine with unsplash but not with svgbox.net

```
images: {
    domains: [
      's2.svgbox.net',
      'avatars.dicebear.com',
      'lh3.googleusercontent.com',
      'images.unsplash.com',
    ],
  },
```